# How force spring to inject from not named implementation

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I am using the Atlassian SDK to create a plugin. There is an interface named `FieldHtmlFactory` in the SDK which a class named `fieldHtmlFactory` has implemented it so we can use injection to access them. But for some reason, I should make another implementation in some cases from this interface. Now I can inject my own class by its name but as SDK implementation has not any name I cannot use it anymore. Is there a way to force spring to use SDK's implementation in this case?

SDK interface:

```
@ExperimentalApi
public interface FieldHtmlFactory {
    List<FieldHtmlBean> getCreateFields(ApplicationUser var1, OperationContext var2, Action var3, MutableIssue var4, boolean var5, List<String> var6);

    List<FieldHtmlBean> getLinkedIssueCreateFields(ApplicationUser var1, OperationContext var2, Action var3, MutableIssue var4, Issue var5, boolean var6, List<String> var7);

    List<FieldHtmlBean> getEditFields(ApplicationUser var1, OperationContext var2, Action var3, Issue var4, boolean var5);

    List<FieldHtmlBean> getInlineEditFields(ApplicationUser var1, OperationContext var2, Action var3, Issue var4, boolean var5);

    List<FieldHtmlBean> getSubTaskCreateFields(ApplicationUser var1, OperationContext var2, Action var3, MutableIssue var4, boolean var5, List<String> var6);
}
```

SDK implementation:

```
public class fieldHtmlFactory implement FieldHtmlFactory{
    ...
}
```

My implementaion:

```
@Named("FieldEditorFactoryImpl")
public class EditorHtmlFactoryImpl implement FieldHtmlFactory{
    ...
}
```

Use somewhere my class:

```
 @Autowired
 public MyREST(@Named("FieldEditorFactoryImpl") FieldHtmlFactory fieldHtmlFactory, ...)
```

I need something like this to use SDK class, but, it dosen't work:

```
 @Autowired
 public MyREST(@Named("") FieldHtmlFactory fieldHtmlFactory, ...)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so there are two different beans, the one provided by the SDK, probably defined by some auto-configuration, and your own.

It would be useful to have the SDK one as a @Primary bean, but you'll need to see exactly how it's defined. Normally it schould be annotated with @ConditionalOnMissingBean, so you could define two different ones yourself, but it apparently is not in your case.

A dirty fix is to use it's default name, which is the simple class name.

```
@Autowired
public MyREST(@Named("fieldHtmlFactory") FieldHtmlFactory fieldHtmlFactory, ...)
```

Comment: But how spring detect that which implement should be wired? And I don't use method level injection, All are constructor level. When I don't use name then it shows me an error : expected single matching bean but found 2: FieldEditorFactoryImpl,fieldHtmlFactory

Comment: OK, Sorry I didn't read your question in enough detail. IIRC the default name is the simple class name. I'll update my answer.

Comment: The dirty way worked ;) This is an unusual situation and the dirty way is enough to work